# Youtube Android/IOS SDKs don't seem to count views when playing

Tags: android, ios, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I've built a custom app that uses the Youtube Android and IOS SDKs to play videos. I have noticed that the views of these videos in the app do not seem to be counting towards the overall view count. This is problematic - is there any way to make Youtube views in the app count? Perhaps if I switch off auto-play of videos in the SDK? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My developed app count views of video.
If you send me your target video title name or ID, I will test views through my app.

Comment: Which SDK are you using, and can you share your code for playback here with others who may have this same problem?

Answer (score 0):

**is there any way to make Youtube views in the app count?**

Here's what you need to know about video views count:

Youtube is now strict when it comes to views count. They now ensure that views are legitimate and not artificially generated.
If you have [Frozen view count](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2991785) that means Youtube is algorithmically checking if it's a legit view.

**How views are counted**

> We want to make sure that videos are being
> viewed by actual humans and not computer programs. During the first
> couple of hours after a video has been published, we'll only show
> views that our systems believe to be valid. This might mean that not
> all legitimate views are shown at that time.
>
> After quality views are counted, view count updates more frequently.
> The process of including all quality views can take some time
> depending on a video's popularity and viewership. Afterwards, the view
> count updates more frequently, but keep in mind that we're constantly
> validating views, so view count can always be adjusted."
>
> Check views with YouTube Analytics If you're looking at a video that
> you've uploaded, you can monitor your views more closely using YouTube
> Analytics. However, keep in mind that the [Realtime
> report](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6096647) only shows
> estimates of potential view activity and might not match the number
> that you see on the watch page.
>
> **Note:**
> Analytics views data is based in Pacific Standard Time, is
> updated once a day and has a delay of up to 72 hours. The numbers that
> you see in Analytics reports might be different from the numbers that
> you see on the video page, channel page, Video Manager or other
> sources.