# YouTUbe video count doesn't increase when played through Android YouTube player SDK

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have YouTube player SDK integrated in our Android app. We host the video inside YouTube account and play it using our app. But we have seen that the video view count is not increased when played from app. Is there any work around for this as view count is critical for us.

Comment: Are you playing the video for more than 30 seconds? They used to only count a view if a user has played a video for more than 30 seconds. It may have changed now.

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264930/youtube-android-ios-sdks-dont-seem-to-count-views-when-playing). It stated that YouTube is now strict when it comes to views count. They now ensure that views are legitimate and not artificially generated. If you have [Frozen view count](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2991785) that means Youtube is algorithmically checking if it's a legit view.

Answer (score 2):

Note: YouTube only counts playbacks that are initiated through the native play button.

So do not play/load video programatically. Allow users to press play button.

See also: [YouTubePlayer  reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer)